# Home directory variable for Windows 8

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-8, environment-variables, home-directory

Is the home directory variable for Windows 8 the same as it was for Windows 7, `%UserProfile%`?

Comment: i think yes. i have seen it somewhere else too

Answer (score 2):

To get a list of all currently define environment variables, just execute the following command:

```
set
```

Answer (score 0):

Windows 8:
Winkey +r
%userprofile%

Result: Explorer launches showing Appdata and My Document folders plus all the others.

To get a list of environment variables launch PowerShell and try:

```
Get-Item env:
```